# How to use Union query in a Magento 2 collection

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent, zend-framework

I am working on Magento 2 grid UI component. For that I am generating grid using multiple table which does not have any relation( so I cant join). I am using union to combine the tables. But while trying to use it giving following error.[image: error image]

This is my code:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();        
    $this->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns(['created_at'=>'created_at']);

    $sqlq=clone $this->getSelect();
    $sqlT=$this->getSelect()->reset()->from('procurement_owned', ['created_at'=>'created_at']);                                                      
    $sql2= clone $sqlT;     
    $this->getSelect()->reset()->union([$sqlq,$sql2], \Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL);

    return $this;
}
```

Then I printed the sql query run that directly into phpmyadmin its giving expected output by combining two tables.

I debugged little and found following line form **Zend_Db_Select**  class throwing the error

```
public function columns($cols = '*', $correlationName = null)
{
    if ($correlationName === null && count($this->_parts[self::FROM]))  {
        $correlationNameKeys = array_keys($this->_parts[self::FROM]);
        $correlationName = current($correlationNameKeys);
    }

    if (!array_key_exists($correlationName, $this->_parts[self::FROM]){
        /**
        * @see Zend_Db_Select_Exception
        */
        #require_once 'Zend/Db/Select/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Db_Select_Exception("No table has been specified for the FROM clause");
    }
    $this->_tableCols($correlationName, $cols);

    return $this;
}
```

i don't know what cause the error. please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific table from the first `$this->getSelect()->reset`?

Comment: Yes. but am resetting the columns alone.

Comment: Can you share me the full code please, even  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is problem with getting count form the union query

i referred the following link and fixed the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731655/how-to-do-a-count-on-a-union-query

https://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5956

Then i overridden the `getSelectCountSql` from `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` to get count from union query

```
  public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $this->_renderFilters();
        $unionSelect = clone $this->getSelect(); 
        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect(); 
        $countSelect->reset()->from($unionSelect,'count(*)');

      return $countSelect;
    }
```

Hope someone can use this method.

Comment: I was implementing a custom filter in the new (`2.3.x`) order grid to optionally include archived orders. I decided to utilize a UNION and ran into this same issue - thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

I debug and got the solution, use union select to collection.

```
$collection = $this->_initCollection();
$unionSelect = $this->_initCollection();
$unionSelect->setMainTable('magento_sales_order_grid_archive');

$newest = clone $collection->getSelect()->union([(string)$collection->getSelect(), (string)$unionSelect->getSelect()]);
//Remove from part fixing the issue sql systax FROM.
$newest->reset('from');

//Reset the select object for updating the query.
$collection->getSelect()->reset();
// Set the union query to main select object as main table.
$collection->getSelect()->from(['main_table' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('(' . (string)$newest . ')')]);

return $collection;
```

The result

```
SELECT `main_table`.* 
FROM (
      SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`customer_id`, `main_table`.`created_at` FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id LEFT JOIN `forix_syspro_syspro` AS `a` ON main_table.entity_id = a.magento_order_id LEFT JOIN `shipperhq_order_detail_grid` AS `shipper_order_join` ON main_table.entity_id = shipper_order_join.order_id WHERE (`main_table`.`customer_id` = '534700') 
UNION 
     SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`customer_id`, `main_table`.`created_at` FROM `magento_sales_order_grid_archive` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id LEFT JOIN `forix_syspro_syspro` AS `a` ON main_table.entity_id = a.magento_order_id LEFT JOIN `shipperhq_order_detail_grid` AS `shipper_order_join` ON main_table.entity_id = shipper_order_join.order_id WHERE (`main_table`.`customer_id` = '534700')
) 
AS `main_table`
```

Comment: Have you faced any issues related to Full-text search when using this? any solution for that?

Comment: This union for sales order grid, Full-text search is a different concept.

Comment: Actually I used sales order grid and other table which does not have any related and used your method to join them and everything well, but problem is when I try tosearch from fulltext search it's giving error like "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes" https://tinyurl.com/2x9hcqtt

Comment: Look like you have to debug the SQL query, exec the query on MySQL let see what is error. How to fix with that query?

Comment: when you search using fulltext, default Magento uses fulltext search based on sales_order_grid table but on the other hand in the second table I don't have those fulltext indexes nor those fields that's why it's throwing the error.. I am searching for the solution but no luck till now..

Comment: Why don't you join the collection result to a table and search on that?

Comment: to Join a collection we need some relation between that collection which I don't have.. if you have any reference can please share

Comment: Why don't you store the collection result to a table and search on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149212/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-hoanghieu).