# How to get collection from two tables and show in Admin grid using Union query Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, join, custom-grid

I want to show two table values in Admin grid using UI Component (which has no relation) so using union query it can be achieved.
How to get the collection from two tables?

Table structure 1

[image]

Table structure 2

[image]

Please, someone, help me with this.

Comment: I wouldn't use union. you should create a table view in your database and present this data in the ui component

Comment: I think your not able to understand my question. your talking about the single table, I want to show two table values in one custom admin grid which has no relation.

Comment: I do understand your question. but I would create a table view. just aggregate your data in said table view. If you need to, you can use UNION in the select of the table view

Comment: But I don't want to aggregate the data in the same table view as there are multiple tables to combine and show in admin grid as of now I am just trying with two tables.

Comment: I have referred this link (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149086/how-to-use-union-query-in-a-magento-2-collection) but I am not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

See the below example to join multiple tables in Magento2

```
https://webkul.com/blog/join-two-table-and-create-grid-in-admin-section-using-ui-component-in-magento2/
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I referred this link but for using join you must have relation.

Comment: I can't use join query because I have a different table structures.

Comment: Yes we need primary key and secondary(foreign) key reference for this.

Comment: Yup, but I don't have it.

Comment: @Amy, but you should have foreign key to join two or more tables.

Comment: @Amy, can you post what you actually want from both the tables.

Comment: Yup I know Amit, but i don't have any foreign keys. As I am trying using with Union query.

Comment: Okay, I will update my question.

Comment: I have updated my question, just look upon my table structure.